Postfix replace in body by adding CR
I'm trying to configure Postfix body_checks function in order to add a CRLF when an end of attachment is detected using this:
/(.+)--$/ REPLACE $1--\r\n

The regex is correctly applied but the \r\n is not interpreted.
Is there any way to declare the CRLF or replace method takes only plain text?
